# How to pass text parameters into a Gradle task from another gradle task (not command line)

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm wondering how I can pass a parameter (PARAM) to a Gradle task from another Gradle task that depends on it.

### For example something along these lines

```
task buildDist(PARAM) {
    copy {
        from "$projectDir/src/{PARAM}/ClientBanner.json"
        into "$buildDir/${project.name}/"
    }
```

and call this Gradle task from another one like:

```
task dist(type: Zip) {
    from "$buildDir"
    include "${project.name}/**/*"
    archiveFileName = project.name + '.zip'
    destinationDirectory = layout.buildDir.dir('dist')
    dependsOn('buildDist(PARAM)')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Shapebuster**

The Gradle build script is `Groovy (or Kotlin)` based and can be extended using the supported syntax of that language. So, in your example, you should be able to use the PARAM like so:

```
    task buildDist(String param1) {
        copy {
            from "$projectDir/src/$param1/ClientBanner.json"
            into "$buildDir/${project.name}/"
        }
    }
```

### and then:

```
task dist(type: Zip) {
    from "$buildDir"
    include "${project.name}/**/*"
    archiveFileName = project.name + '.zip'
    destinationDirectory = layout.buildDir.dir('dist')
    dependsOn buildDist("$param1")
}
```